# Missing several feature definitions - an obstacle to b2b upgrade

Tags: upgrade, feature, troubleshooting

During my attempt to join second server to a SharePoint Server 2010 farm I encountered a problem of missing features.

[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [INFO] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [WARNING] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Could not find feature definition by id "11df38ab-5bbb-4304-9da8-221c5c4100b0".
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [INFO] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [WARNING] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Не удалось найти идентификатор определения компонента "395702f0-184c-46a2-9bb5-0a64b048738c".
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [INFO] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [WARNING] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Could not find feature definition by id "4d0d9bec-5103-4663-b88d-27cfab1029ff".
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [INFO] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [WARNING] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Could not find feature definition by id "99ee0928-7342-4739-865d-35b61ea4eaf0".
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [INFO] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [WARNING] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Could not find feature definition by id "fcd4c704-ed7a-42fb-ab30-2bb0ab6494c8".
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [INFO] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: SPFarm Name=SharePoint_Config
[PSCONFIG] [SPFarmSequence2] [WARNING] [11.11.2010 10:06:34]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Could not find feature definition by id "fea264c1-79e3-4cad-b60b-fa9cc3522cac".

As SharePoint_Config.Objects tells me, missing are the following definitions. And that's true, I don't have them in my FEATURES directory.

Analytics\Feature.xml
SpsSsoLinks\feature.xml
FeaturePushdownTask\Feature.xml
OSearchSRPAdminLinks\Feature.xml
BDCAdminUILinks\feature.xml
S2BaseSiteStapling\feature.xml

Any ideas about where to find these or how to remove these records safely?

Comment: Uhm... I find that the first server had a better populated 12-hive... maybe this finding would help

Comment: Yes they were in the 12 hive...

Comment: Looking back, it seems that the first server must have been upgraded from 2007 and the other could have been a fresh 2010 machine. Can't be sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features you are missing are out of the box SharePoint (Enterprise) features. They should be there. It sounds like there is a difference between the binaries or something you installed on server2. And you say you are trying to join a new machine to the farm and upgrading? Could you explain the steps you took in detail?

Comment: It looks as though Alexey did indeed get the binaries out of sync on his servers, so this is a good answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Does your new WFE had the features deployed on it ? If not, you need to deploy the features on it.  It's not enough to only deploy the 12-Hive... You need to do it from the Central Administration.

Comment: The features are deployed to the config database, but the definitions reside in the file system, so I only needed to copy the definitions and the warnings were gone.